# Golang - change build working path on Windows

Tags: windows, go, build, antivirus

I'm testing simple Go program on Windows 8 with SublimeText3 (GoSublime plugin)

```
go run -v example.go
```

and before run it's being compiled inside *..AppData\Local\Temp..* directory. My antivirus program thinks that it's a virus and blocks it:

```
fork/exec C:\Users\D24F7~1.KAP\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build333212398\command-line-arguments_obj\exe\example.exe: Access is denied.
```

I can't disable it and my solution is to change the folder where it's being compiled.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 13):

The `GOTMPDIR` environment var can be used to control the work directory. This is usually preferable to modifying the system-wide temporary directory. [`GOTMPDIR` was introduced in go 1.10.](https://go.dev/doc/go1.10#goroot)

Before

```
> go run -work .\example.go
WORK=C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1002945170
...
```

Modify permanently in the *System Properties > Environment Variables* window or temporarily in the shell

```
# powershell
$env:GOTMPDIR = "C:\Users\MyUserName\MyGoBuilds"
```

After

```
> go run -work .\example.go
WORK=C:\Users\MyUserName\MyGoBuilds\go-build1381354702
...
```

Then you can make the needed antivirus or other security exceptions on the `GOTMPDIR` directory.

Answer (score 3):

The `WORK` directory (seen if building or running with the `-x` flag) is taken from the `TMP` environment variable. Updating that variable through the system properties will change the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I change ouput directory

```
go build -i -o D:\Users\MyProj\out\
```

-o  flag

and put to antivirus ignoring D:\Users\MyProj\out\ directory

Comment: No, the OP asked about temporary build files, they have nothing to do with -o option.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a binary directly using `go build` (out binary is at current dir) or `go build -o /your/custom/path`. Then just run the output binary.

Comment: It's not a solution because in Windows Go compiles in temp folder - _C:\Users\D24F7~1.KAP\AppData\Local\Temp\_ - and only then copies it into _/your/custom/path_. So it's sill **Access denied** error.