# How to change default path to store executable in Go compiler?

Tags: go

In Go compiler, when I do "go run", executable file is stored to a temporary location. How to change this path to store the file in current working directory? I am using windows 7 64bit machine.

Comment: The intention of `go run` is to execute application without storing of final executable on disk. That's the reason, it generates executable in temporary location and once done, file is ready to be disposed off.

Comment: `go run` just executes `go build -o` with a temp path, executes the binary, then deletes it. If you don't want to do that, then don't use `go run`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do something with the binary beyond just running it once, you should be using `go build`, not `go run`. `go build` will put the binary in the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

The folder used by Go to store the temporary executable can be changed by setting the **GOTMPDIR** environment variable.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71197493/1057961

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Adrian and @Saleem, however, for interest sake, you can override the location (somewhat) by changing the location of your environment variable `TEMP` (or `TMPDIR` on OSX or Linux).  This will still create a temporary directory in whatever directory you specify, in which the working files will be placed.  Keep in mind that as Adrian and Saleem say, `go run` is intended for temporary runs.

And of course @JimB beat me to it with his comment which is really the essence of what I'm saying here.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with previous answers. `go install` saves binary file into `GOBIN` folder. So you may change it to have a specific location. However, I don't suggest to do it, because you can always build into specific folder using `-o` option of `go build`:

```
go build -o /usr/bin/app main.go
```