How to change the temporary storage path in the TEMP folder in GO language?
When I run the code on GO, the compiler creates a file in the temporary TEMP folder, which the AVAST antivirus complains about; I don’t want to add the TEMP folder to the antivirus exception. Where can I change the code execution to a different folder?
I tried searching in the settings for changing the file execution path, but I couldn’t find it. where do I need to go to change this in the settings?

Please refer to dodgio's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782750/golang-change-build-working-path-on-windows
